# Hashing more than 8000 bytes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlclr

SQL Server's hashing function `HASHBYTES` has an input limit of 8000 bytes.

How do you hash larger strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could hash 8k (or 4k or 2k) chunks of the input and then either concatenate those hashes or hash them into a new hash value. This might get difficult though if you have to create a similar algorithm (in an external .NET app for example) to compare hashes created outside of SQL Server.

Another option: Lean on SQL Server's [CLR integration](http://www.setfocus.com/technicalarticles/articles/clrfunctionforsqlserver.aspx) and perform the hashing in a .NET assembly.

Comment: thanks Paul, it's a really good solution for internal use. but in this case it has to be totally compliant with sha1

Comment: @SDReyes: Another idea added to my answer: Lean on SQL Server's CLR integration and perform the hashing in a .NET assembly.

Comment: the CLR integration link in this answer is broken.

Answer (score 9):

You could write a SQL CLR function:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlBinary BigHashBytes(SqlString algorithm, SqlString data)
{
    var algo = HashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm.Value);

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.Value);

    return new SqlBinary(algo.ComputeHash(bytes));
}
```

And then it can be called in SQL like this:

```
--these return the same value
select HASHBYTES('md5', 'test stuff')
select dbo.BigHashBytes('md5', 'test stuff')
```

The `BigHashBytes` is only necessary if the length would be over 8k.

Comment: Careful with CLR SP parameters being silently truncated to 8000 bytes - I had to tag the parameter with `[SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]` otherwise bytes after the 8000th would simply be ignored! Took me a while to get that one!

Comment: -1 for misleading readers (unintentionally, of course) into using UTF-8. SQL Server (and Windows in general) uses UTF-16. Hence this will appear to work for many people who are currently only using Code Points 0 - 127, or possibly up to 256. But using UTF-8 leads to problems such as this Question: [SQL CLR function based on .net ComputeHash is not working with Cyrrilic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35273859/577765)

Comment: @randomdude Your experience was due to how older versions of SSDT generated the T-SQL wrapper objects. The default used to be to use `NVARCHAR(4000)` for `SqlString` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for `SqlChars`. But since around the time of Visual Studio 2013, the default was changed to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for both. Still, it is always better to be explicit and use `[SqlFacet()]` as you mention, but folks using the newer SSDT versions wouldn't run into that. Also, SQLCLR only support `NVARCHAR` so it would actually truncate at 4000 chars :-).

Answer (score 2):

Like Paul's idea, one idea that comes to mind for chunking would be to store the hashed string in an XML column, with each chunk as a separate XML element.

Comment: +1 Good idea, though for data integrity's sake I would suggest a single hash value be stored (a hash of hashes.) With an XML structure you would need an extra attribute that maps a hash value to the index of the Nth chunk of data that was hashed.